# How to interpret user search query (in Elasticsearch)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, nlp, full-text-search, interpretation

I would like to serve my visitors the best results possible when they use our search feature.
To achieve this I would like to interpret the search query.

For example a user searches for 'red beds for kids 120cm'

I would like to interpret it as following:

Category-Filter is  "beds" AND "children"
Color-filter is red
Size-filter is 120cm

Are there ready to go tools for Elasticsearch?
Will I need NLP in front of Elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes, you will need nlp in front of the search.  There are definitely no built-in hyponym filters for elasticsearch that will do the kids -> children conversion for you.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch is pretty powerful on its own and is very much capable of returning the most relevant results to full-text search queries, provided that data is indexed and queried adequately.

Under the hood it always performs [text analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/analysis.html) for full-text searches (for fields of type [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/text.html)). A [text analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/analyzer-anatomy.html) consists of a character filter, tokenizer and a token filter.

For instance, [synonym token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) can replace `kids` with `children` in the user query.

Above that search queries on modern websites are often facilitated via category selectors in the UI, which can easily be implemented with querying [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/keyword.html) fields of Elasticsearch.

It might be enough to model your data correctly and tune its indexing to implement the search you need - and if that is not enough, you can always add some extra layer of NLP-like logic on the client side, like @2ps suggested.

Now let me show a toy example of what you can achieve with a [`synonym`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) token filter and [`copy_to`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/copy-to.html) feature.

### Let's define the mapping

Let's pretend that our products are characterized by the following properties: `Category`, `Color`, and `Size.LengthCM`.

The mapping will look something like:

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "Category": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "copy_to": "DescriptionAuto"
            },
            "Color": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "copy_to": "DescriptionAuto"
            },
            "Size": {
                "properties": {
                    "LengthCM": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "copy_to": "DescriptionAuto"
                    }
                }
            },
            "DescriptionAuto": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "MySynonymAnalyzer"
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "MySynonymAnalyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "MySynonymFilter"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "MySynonymFilter": {
                        "type": "synonym",
                        "lenient": true,
                        "synonyms": [
                            "kid, kids => children"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that we selected type `keyword` for the fields `Category` and `Color`.

Now, what about these `copy_to` and `synonym`?

### What will `copy_to` do?

Every time we send an object for indexing into our index, value of the keyword field `Category` will be copied to a full-text field `DescritpionAuto`. This is what [`copy_to`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/copy-to.html) does.

### What will `synonym` do?

To enable [`synonym`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) we need to define a custom analyzer, see `MySynonymAnalyzer` which we defined under `"settings"` above.

Roughly, it will replace every token that matches something on the left of `=>` with the token on the right.

### How will the documents look like?

Let's insert a few example documents:

```
POST /my_index/_doc
{
    "Category": [
        "beds",
        "adult"
    ],
    "Color": "red",
    "Size": {
        "LengthCM": 150
    }
}

POST /my_index/_doc
{
    "Category": [
        "beds",
        "children"
    ],
    "Color": "red",
    "Size": {
        "LengthCM": 120
    }
}

POST /my_index/_doc
{
    "Category": [
        "couches",
        "adult",
        "family"
    ],
    "Color": "blue",
    "Size": {
        "LengthCM": 200
    }
}

POST /my_index/_doc
{
    "Category": [
        "couches",
        "adult",
        "family"
    ],
    "Color": "red",
    "Size": {
        "LengthCM": 200
    }
}
```

As you can see, `DescriptionAuto` is not present in the original documents - though due to `copy_to` we will be able to query it.

Let's see how.

### Performing the search!

Now we can try out our index with a simple [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query:

```
POST /my_index/_doc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "red beds for kids 120cm",
            "default_field": "DescriptionAuto"
        }
    }
}
```

The results will look something like the following:

```
  "hits": {
    ...
    "max_score": 2.3611186,
    "hits": [
      {
        ...
        "_score": 2.3611186,
        "_source": {
          "Category": [
            "beds",
            "children"
          ],
          "Color": "red",
          "Size": {
            "LengthCM": 120
          }
        }
      },
      {
        ...
        "_score": 1.0998137,
        "_source": {
          "Category": [
            "beds",
            "adult"
          ],
          "Color": "red",
          "Size": {
            "LengthCM": 150
          }
        }
      },
      {
        ...
        "_score": 0.34116736,
        "_source": {
          "Category": [
            "couches",
            "adult",
            "family"
          ],
          "Color": "red",
          "Size": {
            "LengthCM": 200
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

The document with categories `beds` and `children` and color `red` is on top. And its relevance score is twice bigger than of its follow-up!

### How can I check how Elasticsearch interpreted the user's query?

It is easy to do via [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/indices-analyze.html):

```
POST /my_index/_analyze
{
    "text": "red bed for kids 120cm",
    "analyzer": "MySynonymAnalyzer"
}

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "red",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "bed",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "for",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "children",
      "start_offset": 12,
      "end_offset": 16,
      "type": "SYNONYM",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "120cm",
      "start_offset": 17,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, there is no token `kids`, but there is token `children`.

On a side note, in this example Elasticsearch wasn't able, though, to parse the size of the bed: token `120cm` didn't match to anything, since all sizes are integers, like `120`, `150`, etc. Another layer of tweaking will be needed to extract `120` from `120cm` token.

---

I hope this gives an idea of what can be achieved with Elasticsearch's built-in text analysis capabilities!